# Attribute "borderWidth" already defined error while using Support Library Design v 23.1.1

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I am trying to use a combination of Navigation Drawer and Tab Layout in the same application. But its giving me an error `Attribute borderWidth already defined` while trying to import dependencies. Find the error below:

> Error:(2) Attribute "borderWidth" has already been defined

My premonition is that this is happening due to a conflict in versions. Please see my Gradle file below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.iinspin.homeautomation"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':ToggleButtonLib')
compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

}

Also find below my layout file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.iinspin.homeautomation.Design.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Any help will be appeciated.

Comment: You need to figure out which library has the same attribute and rename it

Comment: Check in your dependency which libraries have the borderWidth in attrs.xml

Comment: how to find the attrs.xml file

Comment: have you fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of compatability between support libs and compile sdk version

the version is 23>0 
means Compile SDK must be 23 or above

Please verify "ToggleButtonLib" also

Answer (score -1):

You need to find borderwidth in `attr.xml` using global search.  Then you can refactor it.